# JavaFX Taking Input

Tags: java, javafx

So what I am trying to do is:

1) Take the input entered from the TextInputDialog "td" and store that in a variable then 2) Use the input above to make the default option for the Custom Dialog box which is on my ExampleDialog class in the ComboBox automatically be changed to the top input.

i.e. so the next time a user goes onto the Custom Dialog Box the select item combo box will be what they entered in the text dialog.

I tried doing this and creating a new textfield etc. so you may see some random code resembling this JavaFX UI Controls

This is just practice but will learn from this if someone else helps me out.

**TLDR: Taking input from textfield and storing it as a variable for
use**

First class (Lines 47-51 I attempted to make a new textfield [JavaFX UI Controls (TextFields))](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm)  :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MenuDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        Menu helpMenu = new Menu("Help");

        MenuItem factoryPopUpMI = new MenuItem("Factory PopUp...");
        MenuItem myDialogMI = new MenuItem("Custom Dialog Box");
        MenuItem savePopUpMI = new MenuItem("Save");
        MenuItem exitMI = new MenuItem("Exit");
        MenuItem aboutMI = new MenuItem("About...");

        fileMenu.getItems().add(factoryPopUpMI);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(myDialogMI);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(savePopUpMI);
        fileMenu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
        fileMenu.getItems().add(exitMI);

        helpMenu.getItems().add(aboutMI);

        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, helpMenu);

        TextInputDialog td = new TextInputDialog();
        td.setTitle("Question");
        td.setHeaderText("What is your favourite football team?");

        Label label1 = new Label("Name:");
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(label1, textField);
        hb.setSpacing(10);

        exitMI.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        factoryPopUpMI.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                td.show();

            }
        });

        myDialogMI.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ExampleDialog dialog = new ExampleDialog();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        savePopUpMI.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Alert saveAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                saveAlert.setTitle("Alert");
                saveAlert.setContentText("File Saved");
                saveAlert.setHeaderText("Save Successful");
                saveAlert.showAndWait();
            }
        });


        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().add(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 350,150);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Menu Demo");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExampleDialog extends Stage {
    private ComboBox<String> selectionCombo;
    private CheckBox showResultsCheckBox;
    private TextField resultTextField;

    ExampleDialog(){
        HBox makeSelectionBox = new HBox();
        makeSelectionBox.setSpacing(25);
        makeSelectionBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        makeSelectionBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox showSelectionBox = new HBox();
        showSelectionBox.setSpacing(25);
        showSelectionBox.setPadding(new Insets(15));

        HBox buttonsBox = new HBox();
        buttonsBox.setSpacing(30);
        buttonsBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        buttonsBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);



        Label selectionLabel = new Label("Select Team");

        selectionCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        selectionCombo.getItems().addAll("Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United");

        showResultsCheckBox = new CheckBox("Show Selections");
        showResultsCheckBox.setSelected(true);

        resultTextField = new TextField("No Selection Made");

        Button okButton = new Button("OK");

        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");


        selectionCombo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                doSelectionUpdate();
            }
        });

        okButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ExampleDialog.this.close();
            }
        });

        cancelButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ExampleDialog.this.close();
            }
        });


        makeSelectionBox.getChildren().addAll(selectionLabel, selectionCombo);
        showSelectionBox.getChildren().addAll(showResultsCheckBox, resultTextField);
        buttonsBox.getChildren().addAll(okButton, cancelButton);

        VBox dialogBox = new VBox(makeSelectionBox, showSelectionBox, buttonsBox);


        Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogBox, 375, 150);

        this.setScene(dialogScene);
    }

    private void doSelectionUpdate() {
        if (showResultsCheckBox.isSelected()){
            resultTextField.setText("Selected Team is " + selectionCombo.getValue());
            System.out.println(selectionCombo.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TextInputDialog` has a method called `showAndWait()` which returns an `Optional<String>` (i.e. an object that either contains a `String` or is empty).

You can use this to capture the input from the dialog. For example:

```
TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();  // create an instance

dialog.setTitle("Title");
// other formatting etc

Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();  
// this shows the dialog, waits until it is closed, and stores the result 


// if the result is present (i.e. if a string was entered) call doSomething() on it
result.ifPresent(string -> {
    doSomething(string);
})
```

Here is an example with some surrounding context:

```
Button showPopupButton = new Button("Show Popup");  
Label displayLabel = new Label();

showPopupButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Set Label Text");
    dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(string -> label.setText(string));
})
```

When the button is pressed, a popup will appear. If you enter a string, the `Label` will display that string. If you close it by clicking the "x" button, nothing will happen.